# rails models for address books (company, person, address)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, addressbook

I want to create address-book-like set of models to represent company, person, location, etc. This looks like very typical address book, I wonder if somebody did it already with ruby on rails 3. The question appeared not (only) because of my laziness, but also because "best practice" approach is usually well-developed, have fewer pitfalls, etc. Currently I think about following models/fields:

**Company:**

- name
- has_many :persons
- has_many :locations
- has_many :urls, :through => :urlcatalog

  the reason to have URL catalog is a possibility to assign notes to URL

**Person:**

- name *maybe split to first-middle-last*
- phone
- has_one :location
- has_many :emails :through => :emailcatalog

  the reason to have email catalog is the same as above: one can assign
  "private", "office" labels to it.  many phones can be organized this way as well.

**Location**

- address *optional*
- has_one :city
- has_one :country

  city or country should be present

**City**

- name
- has_one :country

**Country**

- name

any comments on this concept, thoughts, working examples, etc are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You should look up polymorphic associations. This means your location will be better organized and it will be easier to get parent etc...

Good example over at [RailsWiki](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic)

Comment: thanks, in the real application I'll use polymorphic a lot. currently I'm more interested in the general design of such a set of models...